# Show/hide div with link same link should also work for the tab content

Tags: html, css, tabs, css-transitions

The title may seem little bit confusing so I draw a sketch, so you can understand more what I want to achieve: https://www.dropbox.com/s/luoiz4erg4jfk8y/howitshouldwork.png

The tab function is based on liquidslider

I've start on the transition part, but I need some help...

CSS:

```
li a:onClick + .bottom {
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  bottom: 400px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ea9VT/1/

It should not be a scroll.

Can anybody explain how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is you can use Jquery for this Animation. I hope this done very simple by using JQuery animate function.